# Make a data frame of range of data with a given interval?

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals

I have tried to make a range of data with an interval like below:

```
1   10
11  20
21  30
31  40 
41  50
51  60
61  70
71  80
81  90
91 100
```

I also used `seq (1,100,by=9)` but it doesn`t work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `(1:10) * 10 - 9`

Comment: Or `seq(1, 91, by=10)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it just gives me the first column of the data frame, how can I have both columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two separate columns in dataframe for each sequence:

```r
df = data.frame('a' = seq(1,100,10),
                'b' = seq(10,100,10))
df
#>     a   b
#> 1   1  10
#> 2  11  20
#> 3  21  30
#> 4  31  40
#> 5  41  50
#> 6  51  60
#> 7  61  70
#> 8  71  80
#> 9  81  90
#> 10 91 100
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>